# Pass Scala.js class instance to JavaScript that will invoke the function call method

Tags: scala.js

I have a simple Scala.js class (Scala-2.12.10 and Scala-js 0.6.31):

```
class Foo extends js.Object {
def apply() = { println("apply") }
def bar() = { println("bar") }
}

val myfoo = new Foo()
```

An instance of Foo will be passed to a JavaScript library which will in turn attempt to invoke the following two methods:

```
myfoo()
myfoo.bar()
```

Of course, this will not work because I cannot define the `apply` method on Foo since it derives from `js.Object` and that will not translate to calling `()` on the object.

How does one construct an appropriate class for this scenario?

Update:

Here is some example code based on @sjrd's answer that provides for strong typing while encapsulating the `js.Dynamic` complexity.

```
trait FooTrait extends js.Object {
  def own()
  def bar()
}

class Foo extends FooTrait {
  def own() = { println("apply") }
  def bar() = { println("bar") }
}

def makeFoo(foo: FooTrait]) = {
  val jsFoo = ({ () => 
    foo.own()
  }: js.Function0[Unit]).asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic]

  jsFoo.bar = ({ () =>
    foo.bar()
  }: js.Function0[Unit])

  jsFoo
}

val myFoo = makeFoo(new Foo())
```

Now `myFoo` is ready to be passed to the JavaScript library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, the only way that a call like `myfoo()` can be valid is if `myfoo` was *created* as a function value. To make `myfoo.bar()` work in addition, that must be patched on the function value after it's created. There is no way (except proxies, which are another beast entirely) to create `myfoo` as an object first, from a class or not, and make it answer to `myfoo()`.

Therefore, this is also what you have to do in Scala.js:

```
val myfoo = ({ () =>
  println("apply")
}: js.Function0[Unit]).asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic]
myfoo.bar = ({ () =>
  println("bar")
}: js.Function0[Unit])
```

After that, you can pass `myfoo` to the JavaScript code.

Comment: Thank you -- I was really scratching my head trying to figure this out. I am working on a facade and just to make sure I understand correctly, there is no way to enforce any static typing in this scenario since you have to construct the object piecemeal as a `js.Dynamic` (which is what the corresponding JavaScript code does more or less)

Comment: Of course my actual use case has more requirements and needs to store some data from the `bar` call to be used by the `apply` call later. Is that possible in this scenario other than basically using `js.Dynamic` like JavaScript?

Comment: To store data, you can either dynamically store fields on `myfoo`, with `myfoo.someData = "whatever"` (in that case you may have to declare `myfoo` as `lazy val` with an explicit type: `lazy val myfoo: js.Dynamic = ...`). Or you can simply declare `var`s for your data above the definition of `myfoo`, and use those `var`s both from `apply` and `bar`.